# Facebook messager not send message

Tags: java, json, facebook, httpurlconnection

I would like to show my codes but I do not know why my facebook has not got the message.   Thank you very much for help

```
    HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=the_access_token").openConnection()));
    myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    myConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    myConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");      
    myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    myConnection.connect(); 
  JSONObject myTest = new JSONObject();

        try {
            JSONObject recipient = new JSONObject();
            recipient.put("id", "martinxxxxxwang");         
            myTest.put("recipient", recipient);
            JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
            message.put("text", "888");         
            myTest.put("message", message);     
            response.getWriter().append(myTest.toString());             

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        OutputStream os = myConnection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(myTest.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        os.close();
```

By the way, the content of "myTest" is {"recipient":{"id":"martinxxxxxwang"},"message":{"text":"888"}}.
And if i try
 "graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=token"‌​;, 
I was told ""error": { "message": "(#100) The parameter user_id is required", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100, "fbtrace_id": "FEv3jq/ahEq" } }"

Comment: How are you obtaining your access token?  Do you have the rights to read messages from this particular FB page?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: hi, the access token I've got in "/developers.facebook.com/apps/(my app)/messenger/", i've tried "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=token", I was told ""error": {
      "message": "(#100) The parameter user_id is required",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "FEv3jq/ahEq"
   }
}" so I think the toekn is no problem. for your question "Do you have the rights to read messages from this particular FB page? " I think so, anyway I cannot understand it well.

Comment: I have only worked with the Facebook Graph API sporadically, but my advice would be to first get the call working in the Graph explorer, then worry about your Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the recipient Id, if any field of the json not is OK in many times return this error. In your case is the recipient id.